# How to get uploadedFile array from PHP form

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am new to PHP. I succeeded in uploading single image to a form and saving it in the database. But when I modify that to upload multiple images, I get an error saying

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) array.

```
class SatelliteImages
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;



/**
 *  @var array
 */
    private $files= array();


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     *Set files
     *
     * @param UploadedFile[] $files
     */
    public function setFiles($files)
    {
        $this->files = $files;

        //return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get files
     *
     * @return UploadedFile[]
     */
    public function getFiles()
    {
        return $this->files;
    }

    /**
     * @param satelliteImage[] $images
     *
     * @return satelliteImage[]
     *
     */
    public function upload($images){
        foreach ($this->getFiles() as $key => $file) {
            $images[$key]->setImage(file_get_contents($file));
        }
        return $images;
    }
}
```

This is the SatelliteImage entity(single image)

```
    class satelliteImage
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var float
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="float")
         */
        private $latitude;

        /**
         * @var float
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="float")
         */
        private $longitude;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="blob", nullable=true))
         */
        private $image;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        public $path;


        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set latitude
         *
         * @param float $latitude
         *
         * @return satelliteImage
         */
        public function setLatitude($latitude)
        {
            $this->latitude = $latitude;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get latitude
         *
         * @return float
         */
        public function getLatitude()
        {
            return $this->latitude;
        }

        /**
         * Set longitude
         *
         * @param float $longitude
         *
         * @return satelliteImage
         */
        public function setLongitude($longitude)
        {
            $this->longitude = $longitude;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get longitude
         *
         * @return float
         */
        public function getLongitude()
        {
            return $this->longitude;
        }

        /**
         * Set image
         *
         * @param string $image
         *
         * @return satelliteImage
         */
        public function setImage($image)
        {
            $this->image = $image;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get image
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getImage()
        {
            return $this->image;
        }

        /**
         * Get path
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPath()
        {
            return $this->path;
        }


        public function getAbsolutePath()
        {
            return null === $this->path
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        public function getWebPath()
        {
            return null === $this->path
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            // the absolute directory path where uploaded
            // documents should be saved
            return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
        }

        protected function getUploadDir()
        {
            // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
            // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
            return 'uploads/documents';
        }

        /**
         * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
         */
        private $file;

        /**
         * Sets file.
         *
         * @param UploadedFile $file
         */
        public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
        {
            $this->file = $file;
        }

        /**
         * Get file.
         *
         * @return UploadedFile
         */
        public function getFile()
        {
            return $this->file;
        }


        public function upload()
        {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        $imgFile=$this->getFile();
        $this->setImage(file_get_contents($imgFile)); 

        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
        }
    }
```

In my controller, how can I create an array of images and pass it to the above function?

```
/**
     * @Route("/uploads", name="upload_images")
     *
     */
    public function uploadImages(Request $request)
    {
        $images=new Images();

        $form = $this->createForm(ImageFile::class, $images);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $images->upload(????);
    }
```

ImageFile class:

```
class ImageFile extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('files', FileType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                )
            ))
            ->add('save',SubmitType::class,array('label'=>'Insert Image','attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','style'=>'margin-bottom:15px')))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => SatelliteImages::class
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShiraNai7 , sorry but it is not even remotely close. I am still thinking from the java array perspective. I do not know  if creating an array of entities is even possible in PHP. If that is the case, how can I accomplish my task?

Comment: Hi there Madhuka. What are using your Image form for? Is the intent of the form to post a number of Images and then upload them. This is a good question - i don't know why people have voted to close. It might be useful to show more of your form code if you are using it to upload Images.

Comment: @AlvinBunk, yes that is exactly my intension. But when I post that as the question, they just vote as duplicate. I will show my entities, controller and formType.....thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I managed to resolve previous issue by changing 'FileType' to 'CollectionType' in imageFile class's buildForm() function

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('files', CollectionType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                    'multiple' => 'multiple'
                )
            ))
            ->add('save',SubmitType::class,array('label'=>'Insert Image','attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','style'=>'margin-bottom:15px')))
        ;
    }
```

I also changed the 'files' like this

```
/**
     *  @var array
     */
    private $files;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

However, when I do that, the 'browse images' button disappears from the view. Any suggestions to fix that?

I also tried removing the construct() function. When I do that, it gives me an error in the controller saying "invalid argument supplied for foreach"

Answer (score 1):

This code right here is a problem:

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="60000000")
 */
private $files= array();
```

You need to fix that. You are asserting it's a file, but then you specify that it's an array!

---

**EDIT #2**

Your `upload` function has a problem too. You are returning the same parameter that you are passing in ($images). So you need to change it like so:

```
/**
 * @param satelliteImage[] $images
 *
 * @return satelliteImage[]
 *
 */
public function upload($images){
    foreach ($this->getFiles() as $key => $file) {
        $img[$key]->setImage(file_get_contents($file));
    }
    return $img;
}
```

---

EDIT #3

The buildForm function seems ok. In your Controller, I think you need to create the class and load the form like this:

```
$images = new SatelliteImages();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($images);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $images = $form->getData();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($images);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('some_path');
}
```

Can you try it? Not sure if that's the problem or not.

Comment: I changed that to @var array, but I still get the same exact error. I think the issue is in the setFIles() function or the builder

Comment: See my EDIT #2 section.

Comment: I made the EDIT #2 you suggested, but I still cannot get pass through the previous error, can you please check the builder function in imageFile class

Comment: I don't see your `builder function`.

Comment: Ah, I just added that to the question, can you check?Thats probably where the fault is

Comment: buildForm() function

Comment: Check EDIT #3 since your buildForm looks ok.

Comment: I tried that, that was similar to the controller function for single image upload, But it gives an error, "Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Entity\SatelliteImages" given "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133111/discussion-between-madhuka-harith-and-alvin-bunk).

Comment: Where does that error occur? Which file? I don't have time for chat.

Comment: Error occurs in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php